# How to determine the clicked item in a gridview

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, microsoft-metro

I used this XAML code to create a gridview and add items to it:

```
<Grid x:Name="MainStack" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="628" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1366">
        <GridView
        x:Name="itemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsGridView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
        TabIndex="1"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Padding="130,42,116,46"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard250x250ItemTemplate}"
        SelectionMode="None"
        IsSwipeEnabled="false"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        Background="#FFFB0404" Margin="0,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.489,0.503" ItemClick="MainPage_Click">
            <x:String>Item 1</x:String>
            <x:String>Item 2</x:String>
            <x:String>Item 3</x:String>
            <x:String>Item 4</x:String>
            <x:String>Item 5</x:String>
            <x:String>Item 6</x:String>
            <x:String>Item 7</x:String>
            <x:String>Item 8</x:String>
        </GridView>
    </Grid>
```

Then I tried using this C# code

```
 private void MainPage_Click(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        string output = e.ClickedItem.ToString();
        int ClickValue = Convert.ToInt32(output);
        if (ClickValue == 0)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ItemsPageRSS));
        }
    }
```

to make the app navigate to a page when the 1st item is clicked but it gave an error.

Please if anyone can tell me how to isolate each iem and add a seperate click event for each and how to customize the gridview items by adding titles, subtitles and images to the items. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should wrote the error you get.

Comment: duplicate question from same user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833994/how-to-determine-which-gridview-item-is-clicked-and-to-create-a-separate-click-e?rq=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here I am giving you simple example if you can't understand MSDN sample. Just create new project and paste the whole code.

XAML

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <GridView
        x:Name="itemGridView"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard250x250ItemTemplate}"
        SelectionMode="None"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        Background="#FFFB0404" 
        ItemClick="MainPage_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

C#

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var gvData = new ObservableCollection<MyData>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        gvData.Add(new MyData
        {
            ID = i,
            Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.png")), //You can add any image
            Title = "Title " + i,
            Subtitle = "Subtitle " + i
        });
    }
    itemGridView.ItemsSource = gvData;
}

private void MainPage_Click(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    MyData output = e.ClickedItem as MyData;
    int ClickValue = output.ID;
    if (ClickValue == 0)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ItemsPageRSS));
        //TODO : Do whatever you want
    }

    //.....
    //TODO : Do operations for other items as well.
}
```

You may create `MyData` class outside the scope of `MainPage` (XAML Page) class.

```
public class MyData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public ImageSource Image { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks I will try it now  tried it, but it gave me these errors namespace name ImageSource not found in MyData.cs and namespace name BitmapImage not found in MainPage.xaml.cs. what could I be doing wrong? please forgive my little knowledge

Comment: I tried, stackoverflow said I didn't have enough reputation to do that. I also modified the code and used it for a list view in a splitpage and it worked but when I created a string array called content to hold the content that will be displayed in the textblock in the scrollviewer of the splitpage corresponding to the item position, it builds, compiles and runs, but when I click on that splitpage it throws and exception, do you understand why?

Comment: What kind of exception ? upvote require more rep point, you can mark it as answer just click on check mark below upvote and downvote buttons